# Fragment Add not work

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have tried to  load a fragment dynamically by adding a fragment(AnotherFragment) to a  layout(sample_content_fragment) in mainactivity .But it doesn't work when i click  button1.The code below have run so the error isn't the Button.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        AnotherFragment fragment = new AnotherFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.sample_content_fragment, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
        break;
    }
```

And here you can see  mainactivity's layout:

```
 <LinearLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/fregment_test"
    android:name="com.example.henucmapus.TestFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="112dp" />

     <FrameLayout
         android:id="@+id/sample_content_fragment"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
    /> 
    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is the fragment i want to load.

```
 import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class AnotherFragment extends Fragment{
 public View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,
           Bundle savedInstanceState){
     View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.anotherfragment,container, false);

     return view;
 }
}
```

Here is the fragment layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="11111111111"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to replace the content inside the initial fragment instead of the fragment itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnCreateView` means nothing in Android terms (at least in Java, Xamarin does have it capitalized).

The correct method you want is `onCreateView`. (lowercase `on`)

If you used annotations, you could see that.

For example.

```
public class AnotherFragment extends Fragment{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,
           Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.anotherfragment,container, false);

        return view;
    }
}
```

And if that doesn't work, you seem to have no `R.id.button1` in your main layout, so there's no fragment transaction being done anyway